# Canvas image rendering quality inconsistent in Chrome when using multiple layers

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

A frustrating little rendering issue, that I only see on Chrome on the desktop.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhxJu.png

I have 2 canvas layers, and am drawing to them without using any libs, just using drawImage to each canvas. So nothing special. But I'm experimenting with drawing background images to the background canvas infrequently, and then stuff that needs to move frequently I want to draw on the top canvas. This seems much more efficient than drawing the background on a single canvas every frame.

The issue is.... if I draw this background image to the back canvas every time (the bottom example) then the graphics look smooth and correct. But if I draw to the back canvas once, and then on subsequent RequestAnimationFrames only draw to the front canvas.... then the background image changes to a more jaggedy version (top example)!

I'm completely baffled by this! I'm not touching the back canvas after drawing to it.... so why is Chrome changing how it looks? All other browsers show the non jaggedy top example whether I'm constantly rending to the back canvas or not :/

thanks

Comment: As a test try making the back canvas an image instead and see if you're getting the same result (you can set src to `canvas.toDataURL()`). You're most likely triggering GPU accelerated compositing: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome

Comment: it appears fine.... it's interesting you mention GPU acceleration; as my desktop PC which chrome://gpu shows uses hardware acceleration causes the back canvas to appear pixelated/jaggy when it's not being drawn to - but my laptop which chrome://gpu shows does not use hardware accelerated doesn't suffer from this issue.